# How to know the part number that I want?

Tags: components

I am new to electronics. But I got to know how to make circuit and make it work. Problem I am facing, I need to know the part number based on my requirement.

Suppose if I want to buy an *AND* gate which works at 9 Volts, then what is the part number for it? How can I find the part numbers that I want? Can I find it on the internet?

It might be silly question for many of you... unfortunately it is bothering me a lot how to know the part number...

Comment: You can use Digikey's (or any other parts distributor) parametric search functionality to find the part you want.

Comment: Finding parts is actually one of the most difficult part of electronics design.

Answer (score 8):

You take your requirements, your specs, and enter them into a parameter search on an electronic part distributor like Digikey or Arrow or any local one. You can search by voltage, resistance, wattage, and any number of different requirements.

For example, in the Logic Gate (Single Function) category for Digikey:

[image]

You can filter by Manufacturer, Packaging, Series, Logic Type, How many gates in a single IC, how many inputs, if it's a Schmitt Trigger, Voltage range, etc. You can filter by many different specs that suit your needs.

At that point, it narrows it down, and you can pick one based on price or other features. They also tend to link to datasheets so you can confirm it works as you need.

Comment: Not to nit-pick (bit I will anyway), your example graphic shows the parametric search for multi-function gates.  The OP would not find any simple AND gates on that page.

Comment: @tcrosley "Not to nit-pick (but I will anyway)" - why bother including that part? All it does is make you a liar.

Comment: @tcrosley OP was really asking in general, using the logic gate as a random example. But I changed the screenshot to Single Function gates anyway.

Comment: Looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing only the supply voltage (9V), and not knowing any of the other factors in your circuit, a best guess would be that you should be looking at "4000 series" CMOS gates. They will run on a wide variety of voltages, they are inexpensive (when you blow them up!) and readily available.

4000 series AND gates include...

- 4073 Triple 3-input AND gate
- 4081 Quad 2-input AND gate
- 4082 Dual 4-input AND gate

Remember that an AND gate is not the same as the more-common "NAND" gate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Passerby & Richard for your immediately reply.

Comment: Able to search Digikey based on my requirements and this is what i am looking for....  I was googling 3 days to find it.  But stackexchange community solved my problem in 10mnts.  Thank you all for managing this website :-).

Comment: I would go to a supplier like Tayda for hobbyist prices on components like this.  For example: http://www.taydaelectronics.com/ic-integrated-circuits/cmos-4000-series/cd4081-4081-cmos-and-gate-quad-2-input-ic.html
Big suppliers like DigiKey and Mouser, et.al. are more suitable for larger scale orders.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to pick a logic family based on your supply voltage of 9v.  Here are the maximum recommended supply voltages for various families (the absolute maximums may be a little higher, don't go there):

```
7400 TTL, 74LS00 TTL, 74HC00 CMOS (TTL compatible): 5v
74HC00 CMOS: 6v
CD4000B, HEF4000B, MC14000B: 15v
TC4000B: 18v
```

So this means you will want to go with one of the 4000 series.

For logic chips, a good place to start looking is Wikipedia's list of [4000 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_4000_series_integrated_circuits) ICs.  The equivalent for 7400 series [is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits).

According to the table, a quad 2-input AND gate is part # 4081, as shown here:

[image]

From the table of supply voltages, plus the table of gate types, you would be looking either a HEF4081B or MC14081B (which both work with supply voltages exceeding your requirements).  So go to a site like [Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/) or [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/) and type in that part number.

I use this approach -- looking in the table of logic gates on Wikipedia first, instead of immediately going to the parametric searches because sometimes I like to just browse and see what parts are available.  I find it useful to have all the different types in one table.

Parametric searches can be useful too, but Digi-Key's search engine isn't perfect.  If you type in "cmos and gate" (without the quotes), which seems like a reasonable search, and then on the next page select Logic Series = 4000B and Logic Type = AND Gate, it will say "0 Remaining".  Then what do you do?

Comment: I explored Digtikey and found the parts that i want. Now i want to place the order. I am located in Bangalore, India. But digikey ships the goods from USA.  So Do you know any online websites who ships the goods with-in india.  Please advise.

Comment: @jsatya no, sorry.